# Как сделать программу независимой от установленных библиотек?

Tags: python

Какие есть решения, чтобы программа могла работать на других пк без необходимости установки нужных библиотек? Всунуть нужные библиотеки в каталог или ещё какие-то способы и их реализации?

Comment: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_freeze/

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev pip freeze выдает все библиотеки, которые установлены, а как получить именно те, которые проекту нужны? И возможно как-то при запуске на новом компе автоматически установить библиотеки, а не заставлять юзера вводить ```pip install -r requirements.txt```

Answer (score 4):

Как вариант программу можно собрать при помощи [pyinstaller](https://pypi.org/project/PyInstaller/)

Comment: Да, рассматривал как один из вариантов. Но напоролся с ошибками сборки и требованием кроссплатформенности от приложения

Answer (score 1):

Так как вы сказали что pyinstaller не совсем подходит вам из-за отсутствия кроссплатформенности, можете попробовать [cx_Freeze](https://anthony-tuininga.github.io/cx_Freeze/). Делает примерно то же самое что и pyinstaller, но можно запускать на любой OS

Comment: неа, cx_Freeze тоже делает запускалку под ос

Comment: На сайте cx Freeze написано про кроссплатформенность ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Надо собрать проект под линукс и он будет запускаться только под линукс, если соберешь под виндой - будет запускаться под виндой) как и пайинсталер

Comment: Буду знать, спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Решил данную проблему тем, что скопировал нужные библиотеки в папку с программой, и в коде изменил путь, откуда будет происходить импорт библиотек:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, 'modules/')
import name #Импорт библиотек из папки modules
```

в `sys.path` находится стандартный адрес, откуда делается импорт библиотек, но 0-ой элемент пустой как-раз для такого случая, если нужно изменить путь.